# How to select contacts from android phone that have either email or phone or both

Tags: android, email, android-contacts

How do I get all the phone's contacts that have either email or phone, and filter out those that don't have an email and don't have a phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this but you will get separate entries for email and phone for a contact which has both.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = resolver.query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0 AND (" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)", 
        new String[]{Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
        Data.CONTACT_ID);

while (c.moveToNext()) {
    long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Data.CONTACT_ID));
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String data1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA1));

}
```

Comment: I tried this - i get only contacts that have phones

it is possible i have contacts that DONT have phones, and do match my criteria by having an email address

I want 1 row to have this: id, name, email, phone

Comment: Then i think you can remove Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0 AND (" and try